# Convert bit vector to binary in Perl

Tags: perl, binary

I'm not sure of the best way to describe this.

Essentially I am attempting to write to a buffer which requires a certain protocol. The first two bytes I would like to are "10000001" and "11111110" (bit by bit). How can I write these two bytes to a file handle in Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert spelled-out binary to actual bytes, you want the [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) function with either `B` or `b` (depending on the order you have the bits in):

```
print FILE pack('B*', '1000000111111110');
```

However, if the bytes are constant, it's probably better to convert them to hex values and use the `\x` escape with a string literal:

```
print FILE "\x81\xFE";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
# open my $fh, ...
print $fh "\x81\xFE"; # 10000001 and 11111110
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 5.6.0 (released in March 2000), perl has supported [binary literals](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/4f19785bce4da39a768aa6210f1f97ab4c0600dd) as documented in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors):

> Numeric literals are specified in any of the following floating point or integer formats:
>
> ```
> 12345
> 12345.67
> .23E-10        # a very small number
> 3.14_15_92     # a very important number
> 4_294_967_296  # underscore for legibility
> 0xff           # hex
> 0xdead_beef    # more hex
> 0377           # octal (only numbers, begins with 0)
> 0b011011       # binary
> ```
>
> You are allowed to use underscores (underbars) in numeric literals between digits for legibility. You could, for example, group binary digits by threes (as for a Unix-style mode argument such as `0b110_100_100`) or by fours (to represent nibbles, as in `0b1010_0110`) or in other groups.

You may be tempted to write

```
print $fh 0b10000001, 0b11111110;
```

but the output would be

```
129254
```

because 10000001₂ = 129₁₀ and 11111110₂ = 254₁₀.

You want a *specific* representation of the literals’ values, namely as two unsigned bytes. For that, use [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) with a template of `"C2"`, *i.e.*, octet times two. Adding underscores for readability and wrapping it in a convenient subroutine gives

```
sub write_marker {
  my($fh) = @_;
  print $fh pack "C2", 0b1000_0001, 0b1111_1110;
}
```

As a quick demo, consider

```
binmode STDOUT or die "$0: binmode: $!\n";  # we'll send binary data
write_marker *STDOUT;
```

When run as

```
$ ./marker-demo | od -t x1
```

the output is

```
0000000 81 fe
0000002
```

In case it’s unfamiliar, the [*od*](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/od-invocation.html) utility is used here for presentational purposes because the output contains a control character and Þ (Latin small thorn) in my system’s encoding.

The invocation above commands *od* to render in hexadecimal each byte from its input, which is the output of *marker-demo*. Note that 10000001₂ = 81₁₆ and 11111110₂ = FE₁₆. The numbers in the left-hand column are offsets: the special marker bytes start at offset zero (that is, immediately), and there are exactly two of them.